# (Solved)Find the number of $9$ letter words using the letters P, Q, and R containing at least one P and at least two Qs.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Please help me with the last question on my discrete maths assignment because I can't get what I am doing wrong.

> Find the number of 9 letter words using the letters P, Q, and R containing at least one P and at least two Qs.

number of $9$ letter words that use all $3$ letters $= 3^9$

$A_1 =$ number of $9$ letter words without the use of P $= 2^9$
$A_2 =$ number of $9$ letter words without the use of Q $= 2^9$
$A_3 =$ number of $9$ letter words using at least 1 Q $= 3^9 - 2^9$

$A_1 \cap A_2 = 1^9$ 
$A_1 \cap A_3 = 2^9 - 1$
$A_2 \cap A_3 = 0$

$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 = 0$

number of words using at least 1 P and at least 2 Qs
$$= 3^9 - (2^9 + 2^9 + (3^9 - 2^9) - ( 1 + 2^9 - 1 - 0) + 0) = 0$$
I can't understand where I am making a mistake because everything seems to make sense.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Not sure why you are looking at $A_3$.  If you are trying to subtract off the "bad" words, as it seems you are, then you should look at those that have *exactly* one $Q$, not *at least* one $Q$.  Your $A_3$ contains all the good words.

Comment: More to the point, $A_2\cup A_3$ contains all the words, period.

Answer (score 2):

You should define $A_3$ as words with *exactly* one Q: $ \displaystyle {9 \choose 1} \cdot2^8$

$ |A_1 \cap A_3| = 9$

$ |A_2 \cap A_3| = 0 $

$ |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 0$

$ |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3| = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3|$

$ = 2^9 + 2^9 + 9 \cdot 2^8 - 1 - 9$

Finally the answer you are looking for is,

$ = 3^9 - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|$

Comment: I would have said you should define $A_3$ as words with exactly one Q.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig agree, changed

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone who helped to solve this. i would never recognise this silly mistake I have made

Comment: @YosefB you are welcome. glad we could help. As called out by N.F. Taussig in comments earlier, please learn to use mathjax. Without it, questions are  usually not well received on this site.

Comment: @YosefB  Rather than writing solved in the title, you can click on the green check mark by Math Lover's answer to accept it as the best answer, which will signal to readers of this site that the problem has been solved.  Other people could still answer your question if they so choose.